# using sleep() to prevent issues with high volume php mail loop?

Tags: php, email, sleep

I was just wondering if the `sleep()` function would have any effect on a high volume (700 - 3000 loops) `mail()` loop.

So maybe after every ten loops, sleep for a few seconds then do another 10, and so on...

Would that help make the loop more efficient?

Just curious guys!

Comment: Don't use `mail()` for highvolume output. It's highly inefficient. Use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make each email a job in a queue system like [Gearman](http://www.gearman.org) (as it has [PHP bindings](http://php.net/gearman)) instead of merely putting them in a loop. This way you avoid the PHP process timing out etc if the mail function holds things up.

In the past I have used the Linux `at` command (a simple queue mechanism) to achieve this with a PHP wrapper script that I wrote: [PHP-at-Job-Queue-Wrapper](https://github.com/treffynnon/PHP-at-Job-Queue-Wrapper).

I do not think that `sleep()` would be a good way of making this more efficient or transparent.

Comment: Seconding this - not sure how `mail()` works, but connection and latency issues for sending mail show up all the time, and not having a good queue to go to would be a bad idea.